# Passing parameters to Telegram bots and parsing using regex?

Tags: ruby, regex, telegram

I have a telegram bot which is supposed to create a new database when a user enters `/newdb nameofdatabase`

```
Telegram::Bot::Client.run(token) do |bot|
  bot.listen do |message|
    case message.text
    when '/newdb.*/'
      bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "created!, #{message.from.first_name}")
    end
  end
end
```

I'm using a regex string to try and capture the user's message and parsing it afterwards.
Unfortunately, the bot does not respond to the given command (In this case, it doesn't print the `"created!"` line."

How can I go about capturing user's input to a Telegram bot using a Ruby wrapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the `/` is a metacharacter in regexp, here is a right regexp:

```
Telegram::Bot::Client.run(token) do |bot|
  bot.listen do |message|
    case message.text
    when /^\/newdb\s(.*)/
      database = $~[1] # get the database name. $~[N] regexp matches.
      bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "created!, #{message.from.first_name}")
    end
  end
end
```

`%r|\A/newdb\b.*|`: use `\A` unless you explicitly chase after carriage return in the middle of the message and use `%r` notation for regexps when it contains slashes. Thx [@mudasobwa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2035262/mudasobwa)

Check that regexp expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/Q0qrtt/1)

Comment: `%r|\A/newdb\b.*|`: use `\A` unless you explicitly chase after carriage return in the middle of the message and use `%r` notation for regexps when it contains slashes. Also, parentheses are redundant, AFAICT.